# Average Time Complexity of Nested Loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, nested, time-complexity

I'm trying to find the time complexity of the following function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) { 
        if (array[j] < array[i]) { 
            //Do something
        }
        else if (array[j] == array[i]) { 
            //Do something else 
        }
    }
}
```

I think it is O(n^2), but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. It is O(n^2).

**Rule of thumb:** Simple programs can be analyzed by counting the nested loops of the program. A single loop over n items yields f( n ) = n. A loop within a loop yields f( n ) = n^2. A loop within a loop within a loop yields f( n ) = n^3.

You can also check with the link below for,

[How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Hope this helps!